# JLabel is not placed in the frame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to add an image using a label like this:

```
ImageIcon soldierImg = new ImageIcon("soldier.png");
JLabel lblSoldier = new JLabel(soldierImg);

lblSoldier.setLocation(20, 20);
lblSoldier.setSize(100,100);

lblSoldier.setVisible(true);
this.add(lblSoldier);
```

What I get is that when I run that code nothing is inserted into the frame, in fact nothing is shown. What am I wrong?

Comment: This `lblSoldier.setSize(100,100); lblSoldier.setVisible(true); this.add(lblSoldier);` should instead be `this.add(lblSoldier); this.pack(); lblSoldier.setVisible(true);` I.E. 1) add the label. 2) pack the frame to the correct size instead of trying to guess how big it needs to be. This also validates the components added, ready for.. 3) .. displaying the frame.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i have already tried to do this but nothing to do, it is the same thing

Comment: @AndrewThompson If i set the text on the label it works, but the problem is the image in fact if I set the text what is shown is only the setted string

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the image file is in the current working directory.  You can try using `System.out.println(new File("soldier.png").exists());` to see if the file exists at the current working location.  Please note though, if the working directory changes, the file will no longer be reachable.  Better to embed the resource within the app class path and use `Class#getResource`.  It's also better to use `ImageIO.read` as it will not only return a fully realised image, but throw an error if it can't be read for some reason

Comment: [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: See [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) for more details

Comment: The current working directory is the value returned by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: @Abra Or `new File(".")` if you can't remember the system property 

Comment: *"i have already tried to do this"* [Edit] to add a [mre] of the current code. Hot-link to an image first to check it works (to show the image). If it does, then implement the advice of @MadProgrammer about embedded resources.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What folder should I place the image on? .exist() returns false

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just placed the image inside the project root, now it goes